# creating JSON format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to create JSON object like below,

```
{"Validate":"Check","Parameters":[{"name":"Greg", "value":"1"},{"name":"Mike","value":"2"}]};
```

and I have two arrays like below,

```
["Greg", "Mike] and ["1", "2"]
```

What is the best way to combine these arrays to populate the JSON object I described above by using JS?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using map

```
let names = ["Greg", "Mike"];
let values = ["1", "2"];
let parameters = names.map((name, index) => ({name: name, value: values[index]}))
let json = {"Validate":"Check","Parameters":parameters};
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```js
var keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];
var nums = [1, 2, 3]

var result = {};
keys.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = nums[i]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: no, I need to match with name and value element inside of Parameter

Comment: look at the original post, there are named keys in the object. One might ask why the data is beginning in this state and why the application isnt setting the data in an object that fits the requirements to begin with, but that isnt the question... the answer is a start but needs more grroming

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary object with the key names for the given arrays and assign values to the object at same index and return the array.

```js
var names = ["Greg", "Mike"],
    values = ["1", "2"],
    temp = { name: names, value: values },
    object = Object.keys(temp).reduce(function (r, k) {
        temp[k].forEach(function (v, i) {
            r[i] = r[i] || {};
            r[i][k] = v;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```